# Facebook tab application without Canvas URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

You know when you create a tab application you have Page Tab section with Page Tab URL: and Secure Page Tab URL:. In my app i want to use FB.init for Fb.login but if I call FB.init i get this error.

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

And this is because I dont complete the App on Facebook section from the App configuration, the idea is that i don`t want to complete. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It might sound counterintuitive, but in your app settings (right near where you set up your Page Tab URLs) you need to open the **Website with Facebook Login** section and fill in a **Site URL**. A typical example would be `http://mydomain.gov:8080/`, but you can include a longer path than `/` if you want. Also, if you haven't already filled in **App Domains**, add a domain there to match the Site URL. In my example, it would be `mydomain.gov`.

The pages that you use the JS SDK on, as well as your `redirect_uri` in any dialog URLs, needs to begin with the **Site URL** that you configure.